# 'Things are going/doing well.' and 'She is going/doing well.' Which verb to use in each case?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

In French, you could use the verb 'go' in both cases:

> 'Les choses vont bien.', meaning 'Things are turning out all right.'

and

> 'Elle va bien.', meaning 'She is in good (physical and mental) health'.

How about in English?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's the same verb for both contexts in French, but in English we usually speak of ***someone*** DOING well (often, *... for themselves*, financially or health-wise), but ***something*** GOING well (often, from the perspective of the speaker, who wants the thing to be successful).

> *The **patient** is **doing** well* (responding to treatment, on the road to recovery)
>    *The **project** is **going** well* (it's on track to meet its target)

---

Consider also the formulaic greeting ***How do you do?*** - that's a bit "dated" today, but many of us still use the alternative ***How [are] you doing?*** You won't often hear ***How [are] you going?***, though.

Answer (score -1):

People can 'do' or 'go'; and things can neither 'do', nor can they 'go'. That said, however, if the subject of the verb is 'a **thing**' or 'some things', then you should use the verb '**go**';
So,

> Things are going well.

On the other hand, if the subject of the verb is 'a **person**' or 'some people', then you should use the verb '**do**';
So,

> Gwendoline is doing well.

Note, however, that it does not mean 'Gwendoline is in good (physical and/or mental) health' but 'Gwendoline is successful,', 'Gwendoline achieves her goals.'

Comment: Google Books claims over 10,000 written instances of [*the patient is doing well*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+patient+is+doing+well%22). Perhaps a handful of them are being used to mean the patient is gaining financially (or "achieving her goals", in some other way), but the vast majority will mean ***in*** (or ***moving towards***) ***good health***.

Comment: What do you mean by "things can neither 'do', nor can they 'go'"? Things go places and do things. For example, "How's your new widget maker?" "It's doing a good job making widgets, but it's so noisy." "Where is that bus going?" "It's going back to the bus barn."

Comment: @Juhasz: Things don't go places, YOU put them here and there, and things don't do things, YOU use them to do things, is what I mean.